# What is real identity of Kagari?

Tags: steins-gate

Who is Kagari Shiina? What is her real identity? She looked so much similar to Kurisu Makise. Is she her daughter? *Steins;Gate 0* ended without revealing her true identity, so I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kagari is Mayuri's adopted daughter from 2036, in the Beta World Line (Divergence 1.129848%). She time traveled with Suzuha into the past, but got separated in 1998.

She is a war orphan and her true name is not known due to her family registry being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also didn't knew that those numbers were divergence percentage, so thanks for mentioning that too. Although, how do you know that the family registry was destroyed? Was it in any episode or manga chapter?

Comment: This is from the visual novel.

Comment: If this is based off the visual novel, you're missing some pretty vital details about how the visual novel handled Kagari's identity, like how she was literally the vessel for Kurisu's memories in one timeline. I think her "identity" is more broad than simply her origins. And of course, it's important to note that the plot of the anime and visual novel diverge significantly in *Steins;Gate 0* (as compared to *Steins;Gate*, where the anime and VN basically follow the same plot, with only a few minor differences).